# Is it possible to deploy HBase component in Cloud platform

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, cloud, hbase

Is possible to deploy the HBase component in Cloud Platform. If so, how to manage ACL?

Comment: This are two diferent questions, as well please post what you have tried and what are the concrete issues you have had when deploying them.

Comment: Planning to use Hbase in cloud platform; exploring possible solutions and its security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deploy with the help of [Dataproc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc)

Here is a [complete guide](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/components/hbase) you will need to deploy it with the use of the following gcloud command

```
gcloud beta dataproc clusters create cluster-name \
--optional-components=HBASE,ZOOKEEPER \
--region=region \
--image-version=1.5 \
--enable-component-gateway \
... other flags
```

Please keep in mind that

> The HBase component requires the installation of the Zookeeper component

so you should keep it on the optional_component flag